# Filter query by an element from inner json array

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-12, json-path-expression

Simple table in PostgreSQL 12.3

```sql
create table aaa(id integer, data json);
```

In `data` column stores JSON with the following form:

```json
{
    "foo": 1,
    "persons": [
        {
            "name": "2fdsdsd",
            "test": {
                "id": "123",
                "age": 32
            }
        }
    ],
    "some_prop": "123"
}
```

I need to find all records from `aaa` where `test.id = '123'` or where `test = null`.

Comment: It's `integer` not `indeger`. Your example json is invalid because of unmatched quotes. Are you actually using `json` type or `jsonb`? What have you tried so far? By *second one* you mean those records where `test.id` is either `'123'` or `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's `jsonb`, you can use [`@?`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) operator with a jsonpath: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8ev8AfC2)

```sql
select id, jsonb_pretty(data) from aaa
where data @? '$.persons[*].test?(@.id=="123" || @==null)';
```

Which means roughly

1. Take what's under `persons` key
2. Assume it's an array and inspect all its elements
3. In each element check `test` key
4. Under `test`, see if value for key `id` is `'123'` or if the whole `test` is `null`.

If it's a plain `json`, you can [cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) it:

```
select id, jsonb_pretty(data::jsonb) from aaa
where data::jsonb @? '$.persons[*].test?(@.id=="123" || @==null)';
```

Comment: this is exactly what i need, tnx @Zegarek